# Sorting mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql

I get from db rows in order  10, 12, 13, 21, 06, 02, 08

I need that this will be sorted like this: 02, 06, 08, 10, 12, 13, 21

Order by field ASC doesnt work i need. I tried remove zeros and then sort array, but no results. Any thoughts?

Omeri

sort(ARRAY) did the trick

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT l, item, l, s FROM tr WHERE s = '".$_POST['size']."'  AND type = '".$type."' ORDER BY l ASC";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $type = '<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled"></option>';

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                 $caption[] = $row;
            }
            sort($caption);
            foreach($caption as $row) {     

                    $length = substr($row['item'], strrpos($row['item'], '-') + 1);


                    $type .= '<option value="'.$length.'">'.$length.'</option>';
            }
```

Comment: you can sort using mysql why php? use order by clause of mysql

Comment: it is sorting in mysql query. But somehow the order is like 10, 12, 13, 21, 06, 02, 08

Comment: Please show the table definition and your complete select.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM tr WHERE s = '".$_POST['size']."'  AND type = '".$type."' ORDER BY l ASC";

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
$caption[] = $row;
}
ksort($caption);
foreach($caption as $row) {   
      
$length = substr($row['item'], strrpos($row['item'], '-') + 1);
      
if($length[0] == 0){
 $length = substr($length, 1);
}
$type .= '<option value="'.$length.'">'.$length.'</option>';

}

Answer (score 1):

change the column type of those numbers to `INT` then u get them ordered.
i think you have your colum now as `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`

Answer (score 1):

@Eric Petroelje I would use:

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY CAST(col AS SIGNED) ASC`

Or add zeros in front of all your numbers. For example, 1 becomes 0001 and 2 becomes 0002 that way you will have your zeros and they will also sort. Oh, I see that you have commented below that your are also using 02 and 2. So you can disregard this.

Or add an extra INT column with the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

The sorting should be done via the MySQL server. If you aren't getting the proper order, then your query might be wrong. Another problem could be that you are storing your numbers as text or another data type?

However, to remove 0's in the beginning, you can cast the variable explicitly to a integer:

`$numstring = (int)$realint;`

Comment: Yes its varchar, because some number needed to begin with zeros. there can be 2 and so can be 02.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the data is stored in MySQL as a CHAR or VARCHAR, so when the column is ordered, it's ordering it like it's a string rather than a number.

Other than changing the type of the column to an INT, you could force MySQL to treat it as an integer for ordering (assuming all values in the column are numbers) like so:

```
SELECT fields
FROM mytable
ORDER BY CAST(col AS SIGNED)
```